# Why `python3 -m project` generates error while `python3 __main__.py` works?

Tags: python, import

Why do I get `ModuleNotFoundError` with command `python3 -m project` while calling `python3 __main__.py` inside project directory works perfectly fine? Here is screenshot from my terminal: [image: terminal]

About files organization: there is only one directory named "memorizeIT" with all `.py` files. Import which I use is just: `import gui`. I have tried to add `__init__.py` file with content:

```
import subprocess
import sys

path = subprocess.call('pwd', shell=True)
sys.path.append(path)
```

It doesn't changes anything. Still cant' run `python3 -m memorizeIT`. What is issue and how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution to use `python3 -m project_name`. In case above it was problem with imports. All I needed to add was `from project_name.module import class`. In my code it would be `from memorizeIT.gui import Gui` for example. Now running `python3 __main.__py` doesn't work, but that's not something necessary. From beginning I wanted to run code as package and now it is possible. Here is link to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) which helped.